# Fastapi many to many relation with extra relationships

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I am developing above database with many to many relationship and a additionally I need add in intermediate table a relationship many to one but I can't get this las relationship with others.
What's a proper way to define many-to-many relationships in a pydantic model with extra data as relationship.

models.py:

```
class Devices(Base):
    __tablename__ = "devices"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    description = Column(String(255), nullable=True)
    status_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('status.id'))
    status = relationship("Status", backref="devices")
    protocols = relationship("Protocols", secondary="device_protocols", back_populates='device')

class Status(Base):
    __tablename__ = "status"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    description = Column(String(255), nullable=True)

class Protocols(Base):
    __tablename__ = "protocols"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    device = relationship("Devices", secondary="device_protocols", back_populates='protocols')

class DeviceProtocols(Base):
    __tablename__ = "device_protocols"
    device_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('devices.id'), primary_key=True)
    protocol_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('protocols.id'), primary_key=True)
    protocol_status_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('status.id'), nullable=True)
    protocol_status = relationship("Status", backref="protocol_status")
```

[image]

Schemas:

```
class DeviceBase (BaseModel):
    name: str
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class DeviceRead (DeviceBase):
    id: str
    description: str | None = None
    status: StatusReadSimple | None = None
    protocols: list[ProtocolSimple]

class ProtocolBase (BaseModel):
    name: str
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class ProtocolSimple(ProtocolBase):
    id: str

class StatusBase (BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: str | None = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class StatusReadSimple(StatusBase):
    id: str
```

How do I need to develop the schemas so that the device returns the intermediate table with the protocol and its status?

Actual response:

```
{
  "name": "device1",
  "id": "3",
  "description": "my device",
  "status": {
    "name": "OK",
    "description": "Connection OK",
    "id": "1"
  },
  "protocols": [
    {
      "name": "ethernet",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "ethercat",
      "id": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected response or similar:

```
{
  "name": "device1",
  "id": "3",
  "description": "my device",
  "status": {
    "name": "OK",
    "description": "Connection OK",
    "id": "1"
  },
  "protocols": [
    {
    "protocol:"{
                 "name": "ethernet",
                 "id": "1"
               },
    "protocol_status":{
                        "id":1,
                        "name": "OK"
                      }
    },
    {
    "protocol:"{
                 "name": "ethercat",
                 "id": "2"
               },
    "protocol_status":{
                        "id":2,
                        "name": "NOK"
                      }
    }

  ]
}
```

Comment: It would help me (and maybe others) to put your desired relations into words: You have _devices_, _protocols_ and _statuses_. Any _device_ can have many _protocols_ and any _protocol_ can have many _devices_. (`n:n`) Any _device-protocol_-pair can have one _status_ (`n:1`), thus any _status_ can have many _device-protocol_-pairs. In addition to that, any _device_ can itself have one _status_ (`n:1`), thus any _status_ can have many _devices_. Is that correct?

Comment: Your desired output model for a _device_ should have a `status` field (data from the related _status_ model). It should also have a `protocols` list field. Each object in `protocols` should have a `protocol` field, i.e. data from one related _protocol_ and a `status` field, i.e. data from the _status_ that is **related to that particular _device-protocol_-pair**. Is that correct?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg that's exactly what I want, sorry for my explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

Use a direct relationship from `device` to `device_protocol`, alias the `protocols` field on your Pydantic model with the name of that relationship and annotate it with a corresponding `device_protocol` Pydantic model. Then add `protocol` and `status` relationships to the `device_protocol` models (DB and Pydantic).

---

### Pre

Your naming is a bit inconsistent, especially regarding singular/plural forms. In the following I am going to use slightly different table names (e.g. `Device` instead of `Devices`) and field names (`status` instead of `protocol_status`) that I think make more sense semantically.

I will also rename `DeviceProtocols` to `DeviceProtocolAssociation` to be very clear about the purpose of this table. You'll see why later.

Also, you should avoid using the legacy [`backref`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/backref.html#relationships-backref) parameter.

---

### Problem: Missing ORM relationship fields

This is not something that I would try to solve purely via the Pydantic models. It is possible (e.g. via complex custom [validators](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/)), but I would suggest that there is a much more elegant way to do this, if we adjust the database models (specifically their relationship attributes) instead.

The problem is that your `Device` database model does not have an attribute capturing the intermediary `DeviceProtocolAssociation` model directly. You only set that table (`device_protocol`) as the `secondary` argument to get direct access to the related `Protocol` instances via `protocol`.

But if you want a `Device` to have an attribute listing the associated `Protocol`s **as well as** the `Status` of those `Device`-`Protocol` pairs, you actually *do* need a relationship attribute to that intermediary `DeviceProtocolAssociation` model. After all, that model/table is exactly where that connection is made.

Then, in your `DeviceProtocolAssociation` you'll have to add a `protocol` relationship to the associated `Protocol`, just like you have a `status` relationship to the associated `Status`.

---

### Solution

To make this work, and be consistent with what you already have, you'll need a few additional components.

##### `relationship` from `Device` directly to `DeviceProtocolAssociation`

Let's call this attribute `device_protocol_associations`. Since one `Device` can have many `DeviceProtocolAssociation`s, that will be a list of instances of that model.

##### `relationship` from `DeviceProtocolAssociation` to `Protocol`

We'll call that `protocol` and it will just hold an instance of the associated `Protocol`.

##### `association_proxy` from `Device` to `DeviceProtocolAssociation.protocol`

Instead of having a `relationship` from `Device` to `Protocol` (via the `secondary` parameter), we will define an [association proxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) to the `protocol` field of each associated `DeviceProtocolAssociation` via the new `device_protocol_associations` relationship. We will call that attribute `protocols` to replace the old attribute. It will work the same as before.

##### Optionally do the same with the `Protocol`/`Status` fields

Depending on whether or not that is useful for you, you could again define a direct relationship from `Protocol` to `DeviceProtocolAssociation` and add an association proxy called `devices`. And you could do that for `Status` too.

##### New model definitions

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship


Base = declarative_base()


class DeviceProtocolAssociation(Base):
    __tablename__ = "device_protocol"
    device_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("device.id"), primary_key=True)
    device = relationship("Device", back_populates="device_protocol_associations")
    protocol_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("protocol.id"), primary_key=True)
    protocol = relationship("Protocol", back_populates="device_protocol_associations")
    status_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("status.id"), nullable=True)
    status = relationship("Status", back_populates="device_protocol_associations")


class Device(Base):
    __tablename__ = "device"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    status_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("status.id"))
    status = relationship("Status", back_populates="devices")
    device_protocol_associations = relationship(DeviceProtocolAssociation, back_populates="device")
    protocols = association_proxy("device_protocol_associations", "protocol")


class Protocol(Base):
    __tablename__ = "protocol"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    device_protocol_associations = relationship(DeviceProtocolAssociation, back_populates="protocol")
    devices = association_proxy("device_protocol_associations", "device")


class Status(Base):
    __tablename__ = "status"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    devices = relationship("Device", back_populates="status")
    device_protocol_associations = relationship(DeviceProtocolAssociation, back_populates="status")
```

To create some test data for demo purposes, I'll add the following function underneath:

```py
def create_test_data() -> Device:
    status_ok = Status(id=1, name="OK")
    device = Device(id=42, name="device1", status=status_ok)
    device.device_protocol_associations.append(
        DeviceProtocolAssociation(
            protocol=Protocol(id=1, name="ethernet"),
            status=status_ok,
        )
    )
    device.device_protocol_associations.append(
        DeviceProtocolAssociation(
            protocol=Protocol(id=2, name="ethercat"),
            status=Status(id=69, name="Not OK"),
        )
    )
    return device
```

##### Adjusted Pydantic models

This is again just to demonstrate. You can transfer this to the inheritance structure you already have.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from pydantic import BaseModel as _BaseModel, Field


class BaseModel(_BaseModel):
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class ProtocolStatusModel(BaseModel):
    """Corresponds to `DeviceProtocolAssociation`, but no need for `device`"""
    protocol: ProtocolModel
    status: StatusModel


class DeviceModel(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    status: StatusModel
    protocols: list[ProtocolStatusModel] = Field(alias="device_protocol_associations")


class ProtocolModel(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str


class StatusModel(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
```

As you can see, the `DeviceModel` has a customized `protocols` field with an alias of `device_protocol_associations`. That means when we parse a `Device` ORM object, that field will get its value from the `device_protocol_associations` list.

##### Demo

```py
ProtocolStatusModel.update_forward_refs()
DeviceModel.update_forward_refs()


def main() -> None:
    db_device = create_test_data()
    output_device = DeviceModel.from_orm(db_device)
    print(output_device.json(indent=4))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

##### Output

```json
{
    "id": 42,
    "name": "device1",
    "status": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "OK"
    },
    "protocols": [
        {
            "protocol": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "ethernet"
            },
            "status": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "OK"
            }
        },
        {
            "protocol": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "ethercat"
            },
            "status": {
                "id": 69,
                "name": "Not OK"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Perfect and detailed solution. Good work.